# Django-ckeditor not displaying correctly in html

Tags: python, html, django, templates, ckeditor

I have a little problem, I installed Django-ckeditor in my admin section.
I can perfectly use it in Admin, but when I display on the Html page it is not showing correctly, I'll put some image to have a better visual.

Here is my admin ckeditor, works perfectly!
[image]

Here is my html page, where the ckeditor don't works correctly
[image]

How Can I resolve this issue ? (I use python 2.7.4 and Django 1.7.4)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When rendering html in templates, make sure you mark it as safe...

```
{{ article.content|safe }}
```

See documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I was just writing

```
{{form.as_p}}
```

Instead use-

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form.media}}     //this was missing 
  {{form.as_p}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether Its tinymce, ace editor or ck Editor not showing / working:
try:

1)python manage.py collectstatic

2)python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate

3)  {% csrf_token %}
{{form.media}}

{{form.Text_areas_name}}

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked by using `{{ article.content|safe }}` while rendering the page.