# django-ckeditor formatting not in html post

Tags: django, django-ckeditor

I have an issue similar to this previous question : [Django-ckeditor not displaying correctly in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915977/django-ckeditor-not-displaying-correctly-in-html)

except that my settings seem to be ok but still not displaying in the html page. What am I missing?

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'awesome_ckeditor': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
    },
}
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"
```

and in the html page rendering the edited post I have:

**post_detail.html**

```
<div class="post-content">{{post.text|safe|linebreaksbr}}</div>
```

Everything works fine on the **admin** side:

yet it is not displayed on the page:

Comment: are you load all css and js in your app template?

Comment: which ones should be in the template for ckeditor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the html was rendered properly and only missing css formatting to add for the html tags. I am leaving this post in case it could be useful for someone to check for such issue.

Comment: so how did you load the `css`? I have tried to include the js files into my template but still no luck.